# Is there a wifi chip on this board?

Tags: integrated-circuit, wifi, camera, 802.11

I have a [Sony QX10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EVIJWXS) camera, with comes with built-in wifi. I want to to connect wired ethernet to it. I was hoping I could find a wifi chip inside the camera, and solder to where the ethernet traces go into the wifi chip. Here's what the motherboard looks like, -- several chips I could not identify, and none that are obviously wifi. I've added labels on the chips that are to small to read in white.

[image]

There's also a teardown video of a similar model here: http://youtu.be/aH0_dAtKofw .

I could not find any other chips or antennas elsewhere in the camera that were obviously related to wifi. Should there be an obvious antenna somewhere?

Is it possible that wifi is integrated into the large processor IC itself?

Comment: It's quite probable that the wifi controller is integrated into the SoC itself, and only the radio phy chip is external. Even if there is a separate wifi controller, nothing guarantees that it is connected to the SoC via Ethernet or MII/RMII/GMII, and not something like PCI or PCIe. And even if it is Ethernet-compatible, the majority of the chips there are BGA-packaged, whose pads are quite difficult to "solder to". And even if everything worked hardware-wise, the stock software will most likely not work with a different chip. All in all, I would not bet a large sum that your idea is viable...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for an impossible task.

Comment: Vladimir, what on earth do you mean by "impossible task"? The question was "Is there a wifi chip on this board?" and the answer was "No."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regardless of which chip is which, it is unlikely that there is an ethernet connection in there anywhere.  The processor talks to the wifi module directly rather than over ethernet.  Sony wouldn't include the ethernet chips and transformers if there's no external ethernet connection

If you need a wired ethernet connection, you will have to get yourself a wifi router or access point.  Setup the camera to use the router, then connect your ethernet cable to the router.